# Parallelize Matrix::Cholesky() in R

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix, factorization

I have a R code that relies on Matrix::Cholesky. I am looking for a way to use my computer's several cores.

I find only theoretical research papers, not off-the-shelf packages/methods. Am I missing something out ? If that helps, my matrix has a hierarchical structure.

Comment: I think base R `chol` uses LAPACK, of which its possible to find parallelised versions. This may be better supported in Unix environments rather than Windows though.

Comment: Based on a [tiny bit of digging in the CHOLMOD source code](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse/commit/01f502ca15860fe345c39bcc54f9073b5bf5a0ed#diff-3e36ec4722218ba7d508004b05a9fc294bd715ee1b764fd3c40e1e7be77498ea) (which is I believe what Matrix::Cholesky is using), this is also ultimately built on BLAS/LAPACK, so I would second the motion to look for parallelized BLAS/LAPACK and see if that helps. e.g. see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#BLAS)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments of Nir Graham and Ben Bolker, all it took was to install open BLAS using (in Ubuntu) sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base. Option "super" must be set to "T" though.